# Как поменять значение value с помощью обработчика click

Tags: jquery

Есть три блока с кнопками,нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку менялось значение value.

Условия:

1. только у того блока, на котором сработало событие.
2. событие срабатывало,когда курсор покидает блок.

```js
var btnActive = "Забронировать";
var btnPassive = "Подробнее";
var contItem = ".container__item";
var contItemShadow = ".container__item__shadow";

$(document).on("click", ".item__button", function(){
    if(".container__item" === contItem)
    {
        $(contItem).mouseleave(function () {

            $(this).addClass('container__item__shadow');
            $(contItem).off("mouseleave");
        });
    }
});
```

```html
            <div class="container__column">
                <div class="container__item">
                    <div class="item__picture">
                        <img src="img/column_1.png" alt="">
                        <div class="motivation__price">
                            <p>Лучшая цена</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item__elements">
                        <div class="item__title">
                            <h3>Представительский люкс</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item__text">
                            <p>Эксклюзивный номер с панорамным видом на центр города Москвы
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item__price">
                            <p>от <span>7900</span> руб./сутки</p>
                            <input class="item__button" type="submit" value="Забронировать">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container__column">
                <div class="container__item">
                    <div class="item__picture">
                        <img src="img/column_2.png" alt="">
                        <div class="motivation__price">
                            <p>Лучшая цена</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item__elements">
                        <div class="item__title">
                            <h3>Дуплекс</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item__text">
                            <p>Просторный двухкомнатный номер с шикарным видом на парк</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item__price">
                            <p>от <span>5700</span> руб./сутки</p>
                            <input class="item__button" type="submit" value="Забронировать">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: "нужно чтобы при клике "  ---- "событие срабатывало,когда курсор покидает блок."    ---- вы понимаете всю несуразность данных условий?

Comment: может быть я неправильно мыслю. В задании было указано 1)Каждый номер может быть выбран или недоступен для выбора. Выбор осуществляется нажатием на кнопку забронировать.
5. Можно выбрать несколько номеров. Как только номер выбран, он становится неактивным.  6. Состояние выбора применяется не сразу, а после того, как курсор ушел с номера после первоначального выбора.